# Can't open Ubuntu software in Ubuntu 20.04 (ERROR: not connected to the gnome-3-38-2004 content interface)

Tags: 20.04, snap-store

this morning I realized that I cannot open Ubuntu Software. When I click on it the pointer indicates that is loading but the program never opens. If I run
`snap-store`
from a terminal I get (If I understand correctly Ubuntu software corresponds to the Snap store on 20.04)

`ERROR: not connected to the gnome-3-38-2004 content interface.`

Maybe the following could be useful

```
>snap version
snap    2.52.1
snapd   2.52.1
series  16
ubuntu  20.04
kernel  5.11.0-40-generic
```

```
>snap list
Name               Version                     Rev    Tracking         Publisher   Notes
bare               1.0                         5      latest/stable    canonical✓  base
core18             20211028                    2253   latest/stable    canonical✓  base
core20             20211115                    1242   latest/stable    canonical✓  base
gnome-3-28-1804    3.28.0-19-g98f9e67.98f9e67  161    latest/stable    canonical✓  -
gnome-3-34-1804    0+git.3556cb3               77     latest/stable/…  canonical✓  -
gtk-common-themes  0.1-59-g7bca6ae             1519   latest/stable/…  canonical✓  -
snap-store         3.38.0-66-gbd5b8f7          558    latest/stable/…  canonical✓  -
snapd              2.52.1                      13640  latest/stable    canonical✓  snapd
spotify            1.1.72.439.gc253025e        56     latest/stable    spotify✓    -
```

What could be the issue? is it that i don't have gnome-3-38-2004 on the list?

Answer (score 3):

I had this error too. I just uninstalled the snap store (snap remove snap-store) and reinstalled it (snap install snap-store)

Comment: Thank you, that also worked for me. Although I still would like to know what caused the problem on the first place.

Comment: I googled the error when Chromium would not open for me after doing some changes on my system.  I needed to snap remove gnome-3-38-2004 and then snap install gnome-3-38-2004 to fix it.